# real-time values in web-app on Bottle with Python

Tags: python, web-applications, bottle

I want to monitor a real-time value that changes constantly on a webpage. Therefore, i simulated the real value as a random value on my script and tried to monitor it on Bottle-created web page. But in order to see the new value, i just need to reload the whole page.
What i want is that the value is updated with a specified time of interval. İs it only possible with Ajax? How could i do that in another way? Here is my code:

```
from bottle import route, run
from random import randint

@route('/monitor')
def index():
    name=randint(0,999)
    return '<b>Value is  %d!</b>' % name

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax (jquery, angular, whatever) is the most appropriate in this, but if you don't want to do it, you could add a refresh tag in your HTML, and automatically reload the page using that:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
```